# External SQL row insert not showing in Django with in same function call

Tags: mysql, django

I have a django view, which calles an external webservice that inserts a row into my django Database and returns an ID which I then use to try and query via django. BUT django does not see the record (running on django 1.2.5, dev runserver and real enviroment).

It is quite simple view:

1. call urllib2 request to an external webservice
2. get return ID from said service
3. `item = Comp.objects.get(id = return_id_new_row)`
   `ERROR cant find objects.`
   I check the DB direct and the object is in there.
4. I replace get with FILTER and when I do a print item, I can see the queryset with the object but as soon as I try to touch it I get an error!
5. I use raw sql in django (not touching django) I can query the row fine, but not get it into my django world?!

Does django some how cache? why would it not see an external insert with in the same call? Do I need to refresh some thing?

Any help welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a transaction issue. Anything you do inside your view is going to be in the same transaction, so you will see changes. But the external service will be using a different transaction, so you wouldn't see changes until you commit your current one.

Have a look at the [Django documentation on transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/). You probably want to use manual transaction management and commit before trying to get the new item.

Comment: yes! thank you very much .. didn't think that transaction would cause this odd behaviour. I added the manual commit decorator and call a commit right before I do my step 3. I guess now in this view I need to call the manual commit every where I break out or touch data .. ?